# Desktop Icons have checkboxes and xes : Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop

Today, mysteriously, the desktop icons on my windows 10 machine
have gray "x" and green checkboxes as an overlay.  The state of
the overlay seems to flip randomly from time to time.

WTF?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: no progress.  The icons went through several more states, and have now stabalized back to "normal", but I have no clue what was happening or why.

Comment: But, can you please elaborate?  Based upon what I posted within any answer, do you have Norton software installed on that machine?

Comment: No norton software.

Comment: If that's the case, it sound like the most likely cause is OneDrive synchronization.  The next time it happens, try the fix-action recommended within the question that I referenced:  right-click on an empty area of your desktop and select `Refresh` to see if that eliminates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your question can probably be answered here:

[Windows 10 Green Checks?](https://superuser.com/questions/957830/windows-10-green-checks)

In other words, people who previously saw the green check boxes attributed them to either Microsoft OneDrive or locally installed Norton software.

As far as each gray "X" is concerned, there is a distinct possibility that they are symptomatic of the same root cause.  From what I have seen, you can alleviate them by doing the following:

1. `Right-click` on the desktop shortcut or file.
2. Select `Open with...`
3. Choose your preferred option, check the box to `Always use this app to open .??? files`
4. Click the `OK` button

([Source](https://scottiestech.info/2016/02/07/fix-the-grey-x-on-shortcut-icons-in-windows/))

Answer (score 0):

One drive is adding it.
It is simply because after an update one Drive decided to sync your desktop with other User folder like documents, pictures public etc.

So this is a backup overlay similar to what Dropbox used to add to the files in the folders being synced.

The only way to remove it is to to go onedrive setting or right click on desktop and click "choose folders to sync" and uncheck your desktop.

I kept it on I don't mind my desktop files getting synced, I have to just get used to the green check marks.