# What are these unfilled — not solid — green checkmarks on my Desktop icons?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, openvpn, remote

I already checked this other question: “[What are these green checkmarks on my Desktop icons?](https://superuser.com/questions/957830/what-are-these-green-checkmarks-on-my-desktop-icons)”, this checkmark is green too, but a little bit different; they are not solid:

[image: checkmars]

As you can see I am using OpenVPN on my machine to access an external network and using Remote Desktop Connection too. Is my computer opened to this network? Is this the reason the checkmarks look like that? If it is how to solve it?

Comment: I am not a Windows person, but based on what I am reading [on sites like this one](https://kb.uwstout.edu/page.php?id=87707), the solid green check means that the application has not been fully synced with OneDrive as of yet. And — in your case — the green check with a white fill means the application has been fully synced with OneDrive. I don’t think this has anything to do with OpenVPN or remote access.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to OneDrive. *When you open an online-only file, it downloads to your device and becomes a locally available file*. So, those apps with green tick are originally from OneDrive cloud and they are downloaded to your local computer after you try to open them.

While apps or files have Solid green circle with the white check mark because you mark them
as "Always keep on this device", so that they are always available on your local device even when you’re offline.

You can read below article to know more about the OneDrive icons meaning.
[What do the OneDrive icons mean](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-do-the-onedrive-icons-mean-11143026-8000-44f8-aaa9-67c985aa49b3)